# How to make node with constant size, where inside text should not be lost?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is a code which makes the flow chart with rectangular nodes and inside text. Here, if text length is different the node size also varies, I want nodes should the same size and inside text should not be lost. How may I do it?

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick}] 
     \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
      \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
       \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training data set};
       \node[frm](n1) {Silhouette Normalization};
       \node[frm](n2) {Compute one cycle from all subjects};
       \node[frm](n3) {key poses through Distortion rate};
       \node[frm](n4) {Evaluation of global key poses};
       \node[frm](n5) {Find data set domain};
       \node[frm](n6) {Dimension Reduction through PCA};
      \end{scope} 
      \end{scope} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

We can see the result of above code into the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two proposals:

1. You can change `minimum width` to a larger value so that the text length will not exceed that size. Here I set it to `6cm`:

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc,shapes.geometric}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=6cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick}] 
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
         \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
          \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training data set};
          \node[frm](n1) {Silhouette Normalization};
          \node[frm](n2) {Compute one cycle};
          \node[frm](n3) {key poses through Distortion rate};
          \node[frm](n4) {Evaluation of global key poses};
          \node[frm](n5) {Find data set domain};
          \node[frm](n6) {Dimension Reduction through PCA};
         \end{scope} 
         \end{scope} 
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. If you want to have automatic line breaking in text, you have option `text width` and `text centered`.

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc,shapes.geometric}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,text width=3cm,text centered}] 
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
         \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
          \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training data set};
          \node[frm](n1) {Silhouette Normalization};
          \node[frm](n2) {Compute one cycle};
          \node[frm](n3) {key poses through Distortion rate};
          \node[frm](n4) {Evaluation of global key poses};
          \node[frm](n5) {Find data set domain};
          \node[frm](n6) {Dimension Reduction through PCA};
         \end{scope} 
         \end{scope} 
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   In the second proposal, you can add `\\` to force line breaks at any point you want.

To reduce the length of the arrows, you can shrink the space between the nodes by `node distance` option. Its initial value is `1cm`. For example with the second proposal, I change `node distance` to `.5cm`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,text width=3cm,text centered},node distance=.5cm] 
     \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
      \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
       \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training data set};
       \node[frm](n1) {Silhouette Normalization};
       \node[frm](n2) {Compute one cycle};
       \node[frm](n3) {key poses through Distortion rate};
       \node[frm](n4) {Evaluation of global key poses};
       \node[frm](n5) {Find data set domain};
       \node[frm](n6) {Dimension Reduction through PCA};
      \end{scope} 
      \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to reduce the length of vertical arrow?

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA I edited my answer.